# Out of all combinations $\binom{n}{k_1}$ select those containing at least a tuple of size $k_2 < k_1$ subject to some constraints

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Consider the set of numbers $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, where $n = n_1 + n_2$ and $n_1 > n_2$. Assume that we generate the total number of combinations $\binom{n}{k_1}$.

Consider now $k_2 < k_1$. Out of all the combinations $\binom{n}{k_1}$ we are interested in counting those containing at least one tuple of size $k_2$ such that any pair of numbers in such tuple is at distance at least $n_2$ *and* such tuple is entirely composed of elements in the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n_1\}$. Moreover, we are interested in counting the maximum number of $k_1$-tuples containing only one specific $k_2$-tuple.

**Example** Consider $n_1 = 8$ and $n_2 = 2$, so that we are considering the set of numbers $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$. Consider $k_1 = 8$ and $k_2 = 3$. We are interested in counting all $8$-tuples containing at least one of the following $3$-tuples: $\{1, 4, 7\}$, $\{1, 4, 8\}$, $\{1, 5, 8\}$ and $\{2, 5, 8\}$. We are not interested in the $8$-tuples containing the $3$-tuple $\{4, 7, 10\}$ because not all the elements of such tuple belong to the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8\}$.

- The tuple $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10\}$ has to be counted because it contains at least one of the valid $3$-tuples, i.e., the tuple $\{1, 4, 7\}$.
- The tuple $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 10\}$ has to be counted because it contains at least one of the valid $3$-tuples. More specifically, all the $3$-tuples $\{1, 4, 8\}$, $\{1, 5, 8\}$ and $\{2, 5, 8\}$ are present, but still the $8$-tuple has to be counted only once.
- The tuple $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10\}$ does not have to be counted because it does not contain any of the aforementioned $3$-tuples.

Then, we are interested in counting the maximum number of $8$-tuples containing only one of the valid $3$-tuples.

---

Up to now I know how to count the total number of valid $k_2$-tuples. It is given by $\binom{n_1 - k_2(n_2 + 1) + n_2 + k_2}{k_2}$ and it comes from the [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. Simply, such tuples are all $k_2$-tuples from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n_1\}$ such that any pair of numbers is at distance at least $n_2$.

However, I do not know how to properly count the $k_1$-tuples I am interested in.

I was thinking mainly to two approaches.

1. From the total number of combinations $\binom{n}{k_1}$ exclude those not containing any of the $k_2$-tuples. However, this seems as hard as counting directly the total number of $k_1$-tuples I am interested in.
2. Model the problem as the total number of solutions to the equation $x_1 + x_2 = k_1$ with $k_2 \leq x_1 \leq n_1$ and $0 \leq x_2 \leq n_2$, where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the total numbers taken from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n_1\}$ and $\{n_1 + 1, \dots, n\}$, respectively, guaranteeing somehow that the $x_1$ numbers from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, n_1\}$ are taken such that they contain at least one $k_2$-tuple. However, also this approach seems hard and I suspect it would lead me to deal with generating functions (and maybe to a non-closed expression).

Do you have any suggestion for a possibly closed-form expression to this problem?

Thank you!